# Visualize Firebase dataFirebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase currently collects statistics for certain page views within my app. After a while, I will have 100's of records in Firebase. I collect timestamp, platform, and the page name. My JSON data in Firebase looks like the following:

```
-KZZV5k4apjZFQKU8cKQ : {
 +
 +--platform: "iOS"
 +
 +--timestamp: "2812373281"
 +
 +--title: "page 2"
}
```

So, when I have a ton of records that look similar to this, how do I go about visualizing this data or getting it into an excel/csv to calculate totals of iOS only or other filters I want?

Comment: Well, you could always write up a little script to get all the data in the database and process it with JS manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in Firebase... you should create dashboards in DataStudio via BigQuery.

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7259176?hl=en

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765